# MS Office VBA changes from 2003 to 2010

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-office

in my company the IT-department finally decided to switch from MS Office 2003 to 2010. In my department we developped many small Applications running on VBA. Particularly all of them were programmed in MS Excel and MS Access.
Now a few weeks ago we received a PC for testing our Applications -> and of course no Application is really running the way it´s supposed to do.

So my question is, if there is any source of information which informs about all the changes made from Office 2003 to 2007 and from 2007 to 2010 - especially concerning the VBA syntax and functions. I read something about single changes but couldn´t find a summary.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: For the most part, 32 bit Access 2003 mdb should work quite well in MS Access 2010, there is no need to convert to accdb for existing applications. What are some of the problems?

Comment: The primary issues I encountered when upgrading was that I had foolishly done early binding. Perhaps the majority of your problems would be solved with late-binding?

Comment: There are some things you should be aware of if your using 64bit office 2k10; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831(loband).aspx#odc_office2010_Compatibility32bit64bit_IntroducingVBA7CodeBase

Comment: Be aware that any missing references will cause strange behaviour including built-in keywords not being recognised. A quick check of the references dialog will show if any references are marked as "MISSING:"

Answer (score 9):

Very little changed within VBA itself.  VBA went from version 6 to version 7, but the only real change was the inclusion of support for 64-bit API calls.  See [What are the differences between VBA 6.0 and VBA 7.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3072356/154439) for more details.

However, the libraries (and their associated object models) for Excel, Access, Word, Outlook, etc. will have significant changes.  The best resource for what changed in the object models is the official MS Developer Reference for each respective project.  Each reference contains a section in the beginning entitled "What's New?"

For convenience, I'll provide links to the ones you specifically mentioned:

- [Excel 2007 - What's New?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb149069(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Excel 2010 - What's New?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff846371(v=office.14).aspx)
- [Access 2007 - What's New?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb245502(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Access 2010 - What's New?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841287%28v=office.14%29.aspx)