# VBA Open URL's in Excel 2013, 64bit

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I'm trying to open links via vba but I'm having lots of problems, here is what I was using previously:

```
Sub OpenUrl()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    Dim lSuccess As Long
    Dim LastRow as Long

    LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    For Cell = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        'lSuccess = ShellExecute(0, "Open", Range("D" & Cell).Value)
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (Range("D" & Cell).Value)
    Next Cell

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

End Sub
```

However when it gets to the `ThisWorkbook.Followhyperlink` part it throws a "Out of memory" even though my system has 64GB of memory.

Trying the shell execute route from: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224816 doesn't work either for me as it returns:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/qiAe0o0.png]

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691831(v=office.14).aspx, http://stackoverflow.com/q/26822004/11683

Comment: I'm using excel 2013 on a 64bit machine as well and I'm was able to copy/paste your sub and follow 15 hyperlinks successfullly.

Comment: @jamesC - there's a difference between having a 64-bit OS and running the 64-bit version of Office.  Most people (I think) still run the 32-bit Office, even if they have a 64-bit OS like Win7.  If you need Office to work with older add-ins etc, then that's a safer bet.

Comment: @TimWilliams correct I am also running 64 bit office (at work) so can't test now from home.

Comment: @TimWilliams I completelyforgot I have an autoInstallVBA where I have #If Win64 And VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCurrentDirectory_ _
  Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetCurrentDirectoryA" _
  (ByVal nBufferLength As Long, _
   ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetCurrentDirectory_ _
  Lib "kernel32" Alias "SetCurrentDirectoryA" _
  (ByVal lpszCurDir As String) As Long
// should have figured out why it was working for me :/ ha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an API in 64-bit office then you may need to declare it as 'pointer safe' and use the VBA7 `LongPtr` type. You can use conditional compilation to test the environment using the VBA7 `Win64` constant:

```
#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA"( _
    ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _
    ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As LongPtr) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA"( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _
    ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
#End If
```

Have look at [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691831(v=office.14).aspx) about compatibility between 32-bit and 64-bit Office with VBA for more information