# How to Open and Close CD-ROM in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform, cd-rom

My Excel is 64-bit. The following code is not running on Windows and Excel 64-bit. Someone from friends can update this code for Windows and Excel 64-bit?

```
Private Declare Function mciSendString Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "mciSendStringA" (ByVal lpstrCommand As String, ByVal lpstrReturnString As String, ByVal uReturnLength As Long, ByVal hwndCallback As Long) As Long

Private Sub command1_Click()
Dim LRet As Long
    LRet = mciSendString("set CDAudio door open", returnstring, 127, 0)
End Sub
Private Sub command2_Click()
Dim LRet As Long
    LRet = mciSendString("set CDAudio door closed", returnstring, 127, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Just add `PtrSafe` in front of it. None of the `Long`'s are pointers - only the string addresses.

Comment: Hi _Comintern_! Can you further explain or correct the code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26822004/1188513

Comment: With the help of _Comintern_ and _Mathieu Guindon_  my problem was solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: I nominate Ross, he seems like he would have the most coding experience.