# Is Excel's Application.Hwnd property usable from 64 bit VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, 64-bit, window-handles

I need to obtain the Excel 2013 x64 window handle from 64 bit VBA code running in a spreadsheet. There are a couple of options to do this:

- Read `Application.Hwnd` ([MSDN Application.Hwnd Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840629(v=office.15).aspx))
- Call FindWindow, imported from user32, e.g. as described in the accepted answer here: [What are the differences between VBA 6.0 and VBA 7.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072356/what-are-the-differences-between-vba-6-0-and-vba-7-0):

```
    Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
           ByVal lpClassName As String, _
           ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
```

The problem is that `Application.Hwnd` returns a `Long`, i.e. 32 bits (I've verified this with `MsgBox TypeName(Application.Hwnd)` within a 64 bit environment), whereas `FindWindow` returns a `LongPtr`, which is 64 bits long in Office x64.

Does this mean that the `Application.Hwnd` property can't be trusted to always be correct in a 64 bit environment?

Comment: It's fine, window handles still work as a 32-bit value in 64-bit code.  The upper 32 bits are always 0 anyway.

Comment: true@HansPassant. Msdn Ref: Last link in my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does this mean that the `Application.Hwnd` property can't be trusted to always be correct in a 64 bit environment?

No that is not true. The `LongPtr` is just a variable data type which is a 4-bytes data type on 32-bit versions and an 8-byte data type on 64-bit versions of Office 2010.

You can read more about `LongPtr` [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251378.aspx)

In case the above link dies...

`LongPtr` (*Long integer on 32-bit systems, LongLong integer on 64-bit systems*) variables are stored as signed 32-bit (*4-byte*) numbers ranging in value from `-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647` on 32-bit systems; and signed 64-bit (*8-byte*) numbers ranging in value from `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807` on 64-bit systems.

**Note**

`LongPtr` is not a true data type because it transforms to a Long in 32-bit environments, or a `LongLong` in 64-bit environments. Using `LongPtr` enables writing **portable code** that can run in both 32-bit and 64-bit environments. Use `LongPtr` for pointers and handles.

**Suggested for further Reading**:

[Compatibility Between the 32-bit and 64-bit Versions of Office 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831(office.14).aspx)

> Followup from comments
>
> However, I'm worried that since FindWindow can return a larger value, a window handle may exceed 32 bits at some stage. And if that's true, then Application.Hwnd would be unable to return the correct value. Or are you saying that a window handle will never exceed 32 bits?

The following link explains it beautifully.
[Interprocess Communication Between 32-bit and 64-bit Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Let me just make sure we're on the same page: `FindWindow` returns 64 bits, suggesting that window handles can exceed 32 bits of value. However, `Application.Hwnd` only returns 32 bits. So if a window handle can exceed the maximum value possible with 32 bits, what happens to `Application.Hwnd`?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you. If the application `hwnd` is say `11872538` then `Findwindow` would return the same value. You can also use Spy++ to check that. `Findwindow` in 64 bit uses `LongPtr`for compatibility as some application may have bigger `hwnds`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that if the handle is a value between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647, then both ways would return the same value. However, I'm worried that since FindWindow _can_ return a larger value, a window handle _may_ exceed 32 bits at some stage. And if that's true, then `Application.Hwnd` would be unable to return the correct value. Or are you saying that a window handle will never exceed 32 bits?

Comment: `Or are you saying that a window handle will never exceed 32 bits?` I am not sure of this so I will refrain from commenting this. What I can say for sure is that `Findwindow` and `Application.Hwnd` will never give you different values for the same window. This can be verified using Spy++ as well

Comment: Just found [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) link.

Comment: @siddharth-rout  - Good answer, but I have no idea what Microsoft actually did with PtrSafe declarations and the LongPtr data type in the compiler, in addition to putting in runtime checks for 32- and 64-bit interoperability: I would speculate that LongPtr addresses and memory do not get garbage-collected in the same way as plain-vanilla integers, as the 'safe pointer' concept is more than just a 32-bit compatibility implementation.