# Programmatically generate self referencing hyperlinks to run macros

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run macro via a hyperlink on a generated worksheet.

Typically, this is done as shown [here](https://www.thesmallman.com/link-hyperlink-to-excel-macro). This method requires the user to manually reference the cell they want to run the hyperlink through. I am able to get this method to work when testing however I can not do that on my generated worksheet. I have the code injection to the generated worksheet already written and tested ([credit](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/vbe.aspx))([credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837006/excel-vba-add-code-to-sheet-module-programmatically)):

```
Sub CreateEventProcedure()
Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim LineNum As Long
Const DQUOTE = """" ' one " character

Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents(Worksheets("##WORKSHEET NAME##").CodeName)
Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
With CodeMod
    LineNum = .CreateEventProc("FollowHyperlink", "Worksheet")
    LineNum = LineNum + 1
    .InsertLines LineNum, "    ###INJECTED CODE GOES HERE##"
End With
End Sub
```

I have attempted to generate the hyperlink with no luck:

```
with ws
    .Hyperlinks.Add _
        Anchor:=.Range(.Cells(1, loc), .Cells(1, loc)), _
        Address:="'", _
        SubAddress:="'" & ws.Name & "'!" & .Range(.Cells(1, loc), .Cells(1, loc)).Address
end with
```

Of note, the final locations shown when hovering over the text are the [exact same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQo3y.png).

Any idea how to replicate the manual method of hyperlink generation to macros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert hyperlinks into a set of cells that just jump to themselves, then `Select` them and run:

```
Sub HyperAdder()
   For Each r In Selection
      ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=r, Address:="", SubAddress:=r.Parent.Name & "!" & r.Address(0, 0), TextToDisplay:="myself"
   Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Based on Tim Williams' comment, here is an update:

```
Sub HyperAdder2()
   For Each r In Selection
      ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=r, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & r.Parent.Name & "'" & "!" & r.Address(0, 0), TextToDisplay:="myself"
   Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Works as intended. I am getting a "reference is not valid." error when entering the hyperlink. Its manageable but do you know any way to get rid of this?

Comment: If the sheet name in SubAddress has spaces it needs to be enclosed by single quotes.

Comment: Should've seen that. Thanks @TimWilliams and Gary