# How to add VBA code to multiple files programmatically?

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have many excel files (approx 200) in which I have to add VBA code (in the `Workbook_Open()` method).
I would like to automate that, is there a way to add VBA code to an excel sheet programmatically?

Maybe with python's `win32` package?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Will all the files have the same code?

Comment: The code is almost identical but must contain a unique ID for each excel file, something like: `Public Const ID As String = "TDW...LC2"`.

Comment: I can show you an example for 1 workbook. You can use DIR to open the file in a loop and insert the code. Is that ok?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel vba add code to sheet module programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837006/excel-vba-add-code-to-sheet-module-programmatically) And [Cpearson's](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) site should also show you in the right direction.

Comment: @Storax: Just saw your comment. Yes it should point in the right direction. That link by Chip should definitely help but this post is not a duplicate of Dave's post. It may be talking about `CreateEventProc` but it is for `worksheet change`. Further more, there is one important thing which is missing in that post. That is about `Trust access to the VBA project object model`.  It also relies on Early Binding whereas this post is not.

Comment: @Siddharth: Yes, certainly not an excat duplicate but IMHO pretty similar. I would expect the OP to do the "transfer" from `worksheet_change` to `workbook_open`. But you are right, the hint regarding _trust access to the VBA Project_ is missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need python for this.

**Logic**

1. Open the file in a loop.
2. Use `.CreateEventProc` to write to the relevant code section. More about  `.CreateEventProc` [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createeventproc-method-vba-add-in-object-model)
3. Save and close the workbook.

**Basic Requirements**

You need to enable access to Visual Basic projects.

1. Click the File tab.
2. Click Options.
3. Click Trust Center, and then click Trust Center Settings.
4. In the Trust Center, click Macro Settings.
5. Check `Trust access to the VBA project object model` to enable access to Visual Basic Projects.
6. Click OK.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim VBP As Object, VBC As Object, CM As Object
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\routs\Desktop\Sample.xlsm")

    Set VBP = wb.VBProject
    Set VBC = VBP.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook")
    Set CM = VBC.CodeModule

    With VBC.CodeModule
        .InsertLines Line:=.CreateEventProc("Open", "Workbook") + 1, _
        String:=vbCrLf & _
        "    Debug.Print ""This is a sample text"""
    End With

    'wb.Close (True)
End Sub
```

Comment: Further hint regarding internationalization: note that the default *CodeName* `ThisWorkbook` called via `VBP.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook")` varies due to regional settings, e.g. `DieseArbeitsmappe` in German :-)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way to programmatically copy code from one sheet except paste into a specific location of the code in the new sheet?

Basically what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have a couple of conditional formatting rules that I only want to be applicable after I've pressed a keyboard shortcut. I want to still be able to use the undo stack up to a certain point.

This code allows the particular conditional formatting to work the way I want it to, and is the only code on Sheet2:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 With ThisWorkbook.Names("CurrentRow")
         .Name = "CurrentRow"
         .RefersToR1C1 = "=" & ActiveCell.Row
End With
End Sub
```

This is what I have for the code to run the copy

```
Sub CondFormat()
'
' CondFormat Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+C
'
Dim CodeCopy As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim CodePaste As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim numLines As Integer

Set CodeCopy = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet2").CodeModule
Set CodePaste = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet4").CodeModule

numLines = CodeCopy.CountOfLines
If CodePaste.CountOfLines > 1 Then CodePaste.DeleteLines 1, CodePaste.CountOfLines

CodePaste.AddFromString CodeCopy.Lines(1, numLines)
End Sub
```

Below is the end bits of the Sheet 4 code. I don't want to delete everything on this new sheet, I would want it to appear under "Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)" :

...

```
SendKeys "{TAB}", 1
SendKeys "{TAB}", 1
SendKeys "^{v}", 2

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

SendKeys "{F8}", 1

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

Loop

SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}", 1

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```