# Generating Worksheet_SelectionChange events dynamically

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a new workbook Programmatically. In this newly created workbook I am trying to hide the cell content in one of the column and display the cell content on cell change event. I want to create a Worksheet event `Worksheet_SelectionChange` dynamically, to track which cell is currently active in the new workbook. This newly created workbook will be a `.xlsm` file as I want to add the code for the worksheet selection change event. Attaching image for reference.

[image]

Here is the code i am using :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
       'Do something
    End If
End Sub
```

I am not able to figure out how I can add a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event dynamically to a newly created workbook pragmatically. Is it possible to do it dynamically?
So can someone please help me with it .

Comment: Yes it is possible if "Trust access to the VBA project object model" is checked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837006/excel-vba-add-code-to-sheet-module-programmatically

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: Why not create the workbook from a template which already has this functionality?