# Include worksheet change event automatically

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

If I create a new sheet in a workbook via macro, is there a way to automatically also include a code for worksheet_change event on that sheet.?

I am creating sheet with name "Group A" in a workbook via macro.

There a cells that have to change to uppercase once the user enters values into it.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837006/excel-vba-add-code-to-sheet-module-programmatically

Comment: See this page for the sub worksheet_change https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change and this one for workbook addedSheet https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.newsheet

Comment: Create a hidden sheet containing your code.  Use that as a template when you create a new sheet

Comment: Why don't you use the Workbook_SheetChange event in the ThisWorkBook module?

Comment: I used the workbook_sheetchange event and got it done. Thanks all.