# Confused with Visual Basic versions

Tags: vba, vb.net

I have Microsoft Office 2007 and Microsoft Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition.
I have some questions:

1. Do macros in Microsoft Office 2007 use VBA 6.0?
2. VBA versions more than 6 are VB.NET (7 and more)?
3. What VB version uses macros in Microsoft office 2010 and 365?
4. What is the version of VB used by Microsoft Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, they do, as VBA7 appeared [in Office 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3083051/11683).
   VBA6 is not to be confused with VB6, which is a different language.
2. No, they are not. They are separate languages.
3. VBA7.
4. VB.NET 2008, [a.k.a. VB 9.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET#2008_(VB_9.0)).

Comment: VBA6 is the same language as VB6.  The "special" contribution of VB6 is the forms engine and the native compiler.