# What was the last common common ancestor of VBA6 and VB6?

Tags: vba, vb6, vba6

I've read

- [Difference between Visual Basic 6.0 and VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/993300/6609896)
- [What are the differences between VBA 6.0 and VBA 7.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3072356)

... neither of them is quite what I'm getting at. I know VB6 and modern day VBA 7 once had a common ancestor for both syntax (i.e. code written in each would do the same thing in the other) and IDE/Environment (at which point they were literally the same language, VBA didn't exist).

I'm wondering when these 2 ancestors were - according to some comments on those questions VB6 and VBA 6 have exactly the same syntax. Is this true? I also read that VB5 evolved into both VBA 6.0 and VB6. Until then they were the same language. Is this correct?

Comment: VBA = Visual Basic for Applications (only available in Office like Excel, Word etc). VB = Visual Basic (stand alone programming language that needs to be compiled into an exe file). The number gives the version. VB.NET is like VB (classic) but uses the .NET-Framework (the exe will not run stand alone without the framework installed). Actually VBA and VB or VB.NET are totally different languages (even if they have some syntax and keywords in common, they are very different). • So I don't really get what this question is actually about?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Well I've read up on VB6 vs VBA. I'm asking what was the last common ancestor between those languages - both in terms of syntax (which I think was identical in VBA6 and VB6), and IDE/Environment (which I think as you say no version of VBA has ever been compilable, whereas VB6 is, so presumably VB4 evolved and split into VB5 and VBA 5.0 or something like that). So what are the shared ancestors of the VBA family and VB*

Comment: Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/993300/5162073) that goes into more detail.

Comment: @BrianMStafford I linked that question in mine. That is VBA vs VB6 in general. I'm after specifically VBA**6** vs VB6, as I'm wondering at what point the syntaxes of the two languages diverged. That question does not talk about the evolution which is what I'm interested in.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I've rephrased the question to clarify, does that help?

Comment: @BrianMStafford Please see above

Comment: VB6 and VBA6 indeed have the same syntax even user forms could be copied, this changed with `.NET` where forms became incompatible and codes needed minor adjustments. • May I ask: Is this a historical question, or is there a practial background?

Comment: VB 3.0 existed parallel to the first VBA. So you can regards VB 2.0 as the common ancester. Please see [VBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) and [VB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic).