# Where to find VBA api documentation for MS Word 

Tags: visual-studio, vba, ms-word

I used to do VB and VBA coding, but it's been over 10 years since I've done any VB/VBA work. I used Visual Studio and it had built in code assist to handle the functions available for VBA work. Now I"m a java developer, so I don't have Visual Studio and I need to write some VBA scripts for working with some rtf documents using winword for 2010. I've created a basic script, which I'm running with Cscript.exe off the command line in XP, but it would really help to know what functions I have available to use with my word objects.

I tried going to the Microsoft website, but couldn't find what I was looking for.  This seems like something that should be really easy to locate with Google, but hasn't been.  I did find some code snippets for various things, but I wanted to know if there was something that shows the api functions for winword outside of Visual Studio?  I've used POI, but I need to run the scripts directly through winword, so that isn't an option.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the docs you're looking for are on MSDN, try [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604039.aspx).

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you for the quick response.  I don't know if it's always been available, but using this tip from within word: (Press the keyboard shortcut, Alt+F11) Opens up the Visual Basic Editor and that did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the many links to resources at the [Word Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905482.aspx)?

That will lead you to resources such as the [Word Object Model Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff837519.aspx).

Comment: This is also a help! Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I used to do VBA development like 10 years ago. Here's what I've found 
word 2010 reference 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff841702.aspx

Here you'll find reference for older products http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726434(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This answer may seem fatuous to experienced VBA developers, but a few days ago I was in the same boat as the OP.  The Java library has fairly straightforward [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).  Like the OP I stumbled around msdn.microsoft.com and found no "master" index of all MS Word VBA functions.  I could always find information on a function or object if I knew what to ask for, but no comprehensive overview to browse.  And to complicate things [VBA <> Visual Basic <> VB.NET <> VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/993300/5025060), so searches often turned up Microsoft's "answer" for something beside VBA.

Part of the problem is, ***MS Word VBA has access to a wide range of libraries***, so no one library (or its API reference) covers them all.  By default my Word 2007 installation links to the following:

- MS Word 12.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library
- OLE Automation
- Visual Basic for Applications

These libraries contain *functions* and *objects*, some of which use similar names (e.g., *MsgBox* is a function; *MessageBox* either a function OR an object).  And that's just the beginning; there are numerous other libraries Word may link to, as revealed by `Developer->Visual Basic->Tools->References...`

**The good news is**, MS Word's Visual Basic editor contains comprehensive offline documentation for the default libraries listed above.  It is accessible through `Developer->Visual Basic->Help->F1`.  This command should open a window with the following Table of Contents:

[image: table of contents]

(if the TOC doesn't show, you may need to click on the pointed-to icon above).  From here you may search, or drill down in the TOC to browse available objects and functions, as:

[image: toc drill down]

As I said, this answer will seem obvious to the experienced user.  But I leave it nonetheless for those beginning their travels in the labyrinth of [Visual Basic for Applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications).

Answer (score 0):

Update: It appears MS has updated/upgraded MS Word documentation. Try:

[MS Object Model Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff841702(v=office.14).aspx)

[MS Word Client-Developer Home](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/word/word-home)

Hope these help the next guy.

dj