# vb6 vs vb.net in microsoft access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba

When I press Alt+F11 I get the ****'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications'**** and I can start a module. This module seems to be in Visual Basic 6.0. How can I instead write Visual Basic .NET ? Can I do it from the same window?

Comment: No, NET languages are not supported in ms-access. just VBA unless you code external library to call from vba

Comment: if I do this externally can I still use the function I write in my microsoft access SQL? for instance  SELECT MyNetFnc(data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at VBA not VB6, though the syntactic differences are small.
VBA is a scripting language for Microsoft applications.
As the comment to your question states, you would need to write a .NET assembly separately and interface with it via VBA. 
[Difference between Visual Basic 6.0 and VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993300/difference-between-visual-basic-and-vba)