# VB6 code explanation

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I need to convert some of the legacy code which is currently in VB6 into C#. I am not able to understand this piece of code. Especially the InStr function, could someone please help me out with this and suggest me it's C# equivalent.

```
For i = 1 To Len(sString)
sChar = Mid$(sString, i, 1)
iPos = InStr(1, "0123456789", sChar, vbBinaryCompare)
If iPos > 0 Then
sRetStr = sRetStr & sChar
End If
Next i
```

Comment: [InStr Function (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: If you have access to Microsoft Office, then in something like Excel, Word, or Access, you can use VBA to help figure out VB6 code. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993300/difference-between-visual-basic-and-vba)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The InStr finds the (one-based) index of a string in another string. The closest equivalent in the modern .Net string methods is .IndexOf. However, I would replace the code you have with this C# statement.

```
string sRetStr = (sString.Where((c) => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray()).ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd pare that code down to this:

```
sRetStr = Regex.Replace(sSTring, "[^0-9]", "");
```