# Invalid outside procedure for class

Tags: excel, vba

I have a strange problem defining a class in an Excel VBA macro.

To do this I go to *Excel→DEVELOPER(tab)→Visual Basic* (the new view is opened). In this new view I do *Project Name→Insert→Class Module* and a new file is created.

Then I try to create a simple class in this file, like:

```
Class VirtualWindow    
Public Sub Class_Initialize()
    Debug.Print "Class_Initialize"
End Sub

Public Sub Class_Terminate()
    Debug.Print "Class_Terminate"
End Sub
End Class
```

`End Class` is in red color, this meaning that it's not ok and when I try running it to see what error it throws it gives me the "Invalid outside procedure" error. I don't understand where is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `Class VirtualWindow` and `End Class` here (since it is Visual Basic for Applications, not Visual Basic 6: [VB vs. VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993300/difference-between-visual-basic-and-vba)) you can define the name in the properties field:

[image]

After this, from another function or class you can create an instance of the class:

```
Private w as VirtualWindow

Public Sub YourSub()
   Set w = new VirtualWindow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up VB6 syntax with another language I think.
You do not have to put "Class VirtualWindow" and "End Class" in your code.
Just:

```
Public Sub Class_Initialize()
    Debug.Print "Class_Initialize"
End Sub

Public Sub Class_Terminate()
    Debug.Print "Class_Terminate"
End Sub
```