# VB6 VB14 VB.net Confusion

Tags: vb.net, vba, vb6

I do a lot of VBA coding and just started with Visual Studio 2015 for larger projects. I haven't done anything outside of VBA since a VB6 class in high school in the early 2000s. I'm trying to catch up and get conflicting answers on what "Visual Basic" is now.

When I read about new updates to Visual Basic to VB14 is this really vb.net? MS dropped the .net from the name?

Does vb6 need to be called  "VB6" to avoid confusion with "Visual Basic" which refers to vb.net now?

And lastly, when I open up Visual Studio 2015 and see the language just called Visual Basic under new projects, is that vb.net?

I don't code professionally so I'm trying to jump back in and get a sense of where things stand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Visual Basic 6.0 and VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993300/difference-between-visual-basic-6-0-and-vba)

Comment: Yes, all modern versions of "Visual Basic" are actually VB.NET. VB 6 was dropped by Microsoft in about 2002/2003 and replaced by VB.NET.

Answer (score 3):

After Visual Basic .net 2003, Microsoft dropped ".net" from the name of the product, calling the next version Visual Basic 2005. VB14 is officially Visual Basic 2015, and is essentially the latest version of VB.net. When you open up Visual Studio 2015 and see the language just called Visual Basic under new projects, that is essentially VB.net.

VB6 is different enough from all the the later versions of Visual Basic that it is typically called VB6. The later versions of Visual Basic are much more compatible with one another than they are with VB6.

Comment: You might also come across references to 'classic' VB - this is VB6 (or earlier) too.