# VB6: What does "string = string * integer" do?

Tags: string, vb6, integer, multiplication

I am trying to rewrite some old VB6 legacy programs to C# and just encountered this. I am still a little new to Visual Basic and I have no idea what this means or what it's function is. Here is the exact format:

```
strMyString = strMyString * 100
```

Its not related to a variable declaration so I don't think it has to do with the string length but I am not sure. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: The answer will be the same here, but i want to point that VBA and VB6 are two distinct languages with their own particularities. Please try to not mix them

Comment: @litelite As programming languages VB6 and VBA are virtually *identical* (same grammar, same variable types, same constructs, same loops, same approach to classes, etc, all running using the same DLLs). See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/993300/4996248 They run in different contexts so there are definitely differences you need to be aware of. It is VB6/VBA vs. VB.Net where the real differences lie.

Comment: @JohnColeman I do understand your point, but i still believe that posts should be properly tagged.

Comment: I interpreted it as a VB6 question, which it was tagged on -- unless the tags were edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `strMystring` holds a string representing a number, the right hand side will coerce it to be a number, multiply it by 100, after which the assignment will coerce the result back to a string.

A simple test:

```
Sub test()
    Dim s As String
    s = "50"
    s = s * 100
    Debug.Print s
End Sub
```

The above code prints `5000`, as expected.

Comment: Thank you! I know this was very simple but I couldn't find a direct reference to it anywhere. The string value contains a floating point so this is exactly what the program was trying to do.

Comment: @LittleBachman If you are going to be looking at a lot of old VB6 code, I recommend the O'Reilly Book "VB & VBA in a Nutshell" by Paul Lomax. It is a very well-written reference book, with a fair amount of short snippets illustrating on how various language features work. Even though I've been using VBA for 15+ years, I still consult it 2 or 3 times per month.

Comment: +1 It is also worth knowing that the string will be converted to a number using the regional settings of the executing PC. This can matter if you need your code to run in different countries